# Deleting deep in an array with immutablejs

Tags: immutable.js

I am trying to perform a complex deletion in Immutablejs, without, what I always seem to do, converting to JS in the middle of the process.

In the following array, I would like to delete every second `{y: }` object

```
series: [
  {
    name:"1",
    data: [
      {y: 1},
      {y: 2},
      {y: 3}
    ]
  },
  {
    name:"2",
    data: [
      {y: 1},
      {y: 2},
      {y: 3}

    ]
  },
  {
    name:"3",
    data: [
      {y: 1},
      {y: 2},
      {y: 3}

    ]
  }
]
```

So that I would get this :

```
series: [
  {
    name:"1",
    data: [
      {y: 1},
      {y: 3}
    ]
  },
  {
    name:"2",
    data: [
      {y: 1},
      {y: 3}

    ]
  },
  {
    name:"3",
    data: [
      {y: 1},
      {y: 3}
    ]
  }
]
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction how to do this with **ImmutableJS**? If I just use filter or array reduce I can arrive at a really clean solution that looks like this :

```
series.forEach(function (elem) {
  let data = elem.data;
  data.splice(index, 1);
});
```

I am just hoping that immutable has an equally clean looking solution.

The doc for removeIn doesn't go deep enough :
https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/removeIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying every element of `series` so I think you're on the right track with `.map()`. Then you want to use `.removeIn` to deeply remove something.

```js
let seriesList = Immutable.fromJS(series)
seriesList = seriesList.map(elem =>
  elem.removeIn(['data', indexToRemove]));

// equivalent form with .update() instead of .removeIn()
seriesList = seriesList.map(elem =>
  elem.update('data', data => data.remove(indexToRemove)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it using 'map' from Immutable List. This worked for me :

```
seriesList  = Immutable.List(seriesList);

seriesList = seriesList.map(
  elem => {
    let data = elem.getIn(['data'])
    data = data.remove(index)
    elem = elem.setIn(['data'], data)

    return elem
  })
```

Anyone have something better?